# Java: How to refactor my code to reduce redundancy?

Tags: java, netbeans

//Here's my code, I'm asking if I could repeat steps for m without having to rewrite.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("First 3-digit number: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Second 3-digit number: ");
        int m = input.nextInt();
        
        
        int n3 = n % 10;
        int n2 = n / 10 % 10;
        int n1 = n / 100 % 10;

        if (n1 == n3) {
            System.out.println( "yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println( "No");
```

Comment: So... a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Locke mentioned in the comment, you can use function to refactor your code to reduce the redundancy. For example, I would create a function like so:

```
public static int getInput(String msg)
{
     System.out.print(msg);
     int m = input.nextInt();
     return m;
}
```

and use that function in your code like so:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = getInput("First 3-digit number: ");
    int m = getInput("Second 3-digit number: ");
    
    
    int n3 = n % 10;
    int n2 = n / 10 % 10;
    int n1 = n / 100 % 10;

    if (n1 == n3) {
        System.out.println( "yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println( "No");
```

I hope, you got the idea.